# Get full computer name eg abc.xyz.xvvx.net from IP adress

Tags: c++, sockets

I want full computer name abc.xyz.xvvx.net which is
Computer Name - abc
Domain Name :- xyz.xvvx.net

I have googled and found this function
GetNameInfoW((struct sockaddr *) &saGNI,sizeof (struct sockaddr),hostname,                    NI_MAXHOST, servInfo, NI_MAXSERV, NI_NAMEREQD );

This function does not retrieve domain name if the machine resides in other domain while retrieves machine name(abc) only. However, it works correctly in the case of same domain(abc.xyz.xvvx.net).

Please help me....

Regards,
Sameer Deshmukh

Comment: What do you want exactly? Reverse DNS?

Comment: Since you specificially name a Winsock API call, what are your platform requirements?

Comment: Have you looked at gethostbyaddr() ?

Comment: Yes I want Reverse DNS for Windows Machine..I have tried gethostbyaddr() but it is also behaving same way as GetNameInfoW. ie. It is retriving only machine name for IP adrress which are on different domain.For Same domain it is retriving Full Name(Machine Name + Domain Name) but not for different domain..Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend you the function `GetComputerNameEx`. The document on MSDN has a runnable sample that fades any other deviced examples. Try to compile and run it, and I believe you will find the right computer name format.[GetComputerNameEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724301%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) While it will only give the right name of your local computer.

I think it over again. Why do you want to retrieve the domain name from an IP?
Per my knowledge, domain is a logical concept. And I cannot find a good reason for a mapping from IP address to its domain.

Since the `gethostbyaddr` sort of functions are backed by DNS service.
For Windows servers, each domain has its own DNS server as name service for the specific domain. There is no need to distinguish a computer by its domain name in the same domain. So I think if you really want to get the domain name from an IP, at least the DNS protocol should support it. However, it is not as far as I know.

Correct me if you have other thoughts.

Comment: Or some configuration problem on the DNS server? since you can indeed retrieve the right domain name on some IP. It's really weird. Good question!

Comment: This function Retrieves a NetBIOS or DNS name associated with the local computer I want for remote machine on different doamin from  IP Address.

Comment: @Sameer I suggest to check address entries in the extra-domain DNS server if possible to see how IP is mapped to domain name.